# How can I Block an entire country's IP in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Is it possible to block an entire country's IP with `web.config`, for an ASP.NET site? I figured out how to block an individual IP, but after researching I can't seem to find the right solution to block an entire country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot block a country, but you can block IP ranges. This approach is used in the most "Country block" scenarios.

Since IIS6 you can block IP and IP-Ranges with the [IPSecurity](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) element.

But this is very inaccurate because an IP addresses have no fixed mapping to a country, or could be filtered by services like CloudFlare.
And also dynamic IP geolocation is working but is often not precise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Maxmind GeoIP database to search for a country's IP addresses..https://www.maxmind.com

The database is quite accurate when compared to other Free services.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you cannot block a "country" from the webconfig, but you can block the IP range for that country using `subnetmask`.

Relevant code:

```
<!--block network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->
<add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>
```